# How to use bindings in controller in an AngularJs 1.6 component

Tags: angularjs

Hello here is my component :

```
angular.module('myApp').component('dendroCtrl', {
templateUrl: '/templates/dendro.html',
bindings: {
    id: '=',
    type: '=',
    mini: "="
},
controller: function ($scope, Api) {
    //Dendro

    var test = mini;
```

I tried this :

```
var test = mini; 
var test = this.mini; 
var test = $scope.mini;
```

Mini is everytime undefined.

How could I use my bindings in my controller ? Thanks

EDIT

This is how I call the component :

```
  <dendro-ctrl id="149" type="Demand" mini="false"></dendro-ctrl>
```

Comment: how do you call your component from the page ? Do you add something like <dendroCtrl mini="value"></dendroCtrl> ?

Comment: print it inside `$init function`

Comment: @Massimo I added how I call the component

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component):

> Components have a well-defined lifecycle Each component can implement "lifecycle hooks". These are methods that will be called at certain points in the life of the component. The following hook methods can be implemented:
>
> - $onInit() - Called on each controller after all the controllers on an element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized (and before the pre & post linking functions for the directives on this element). This is a good place to put initialization code for your controller.
> - $onChanges(changesObj) - Called whenever one-way bindings are updated. The changesObj is a hash whose keys are the names of the bound properties that have changed, and the values are an object of the form

So you can just use:

```
controller: function(Api) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.$onInit = function() {
        console.log(ctrl.mini);
    }
}
```

if you want to display the initial value of the mini binding.

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/yuXrcBg6vbPJ3ETQiDxL?p=preview. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, as I just did.